# Ошибка при компиляции в go

Tags: golang

При компиляции hello.go появляется ошибка:

> fmt imports unicode:
> C:\Go\src\pkg\fmt\format.go:10:2: 
> C:\Go\src\png\unicode: found packages
> unicode (casetables.go) and main
> (maketables.go)

С чем это связано и как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на то, чо вы используете не верную сборку языка (собирали сами). У меня был похожий случай при переходе на более новую версию Go, в которой отсутствовали некоторые пакеты.

P.S. Приведите код программы, возможно вы что-то не так делаете при импортировании.